# AVD manager is showing my AVD 'Size On Disk' as 0.0MB

Tags: android-studio, avd-manager

I am using Android Studio 4.0 in Ubuntu 16.04. I have downloaded the android 7.1.1(No google API) x86_64 version and it runs OK, but somehow my AVD manager shows the AVD's '*Size On Disk*' as 0.0MB and also when I delete the AVD, it shows "**An error occurred while deleting the AVD. See idea.log for details**". And I checked the log file and this is the portion of the deletion process -

```
 
2020-08-04 22:02:04,064 [31814130]   INFO - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Deleting folder /home/robins/.android/avd/AstrobeeAndroidSim.avd
 
2020-08-04 22:02:04,080 [31814146]   WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Failed to delete /home/robins/.android/avd/AstrobeeAndroidSim.avd
 
2020-08-04 22:02:04,080 [31814146]   INFO - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - 
AVD 'AstrobeeAndroidSim' deleted with errors. See errors above.
```

Though it showed error, The AVD seems to be deleted. As there was no sign of AVD, not even after rebooting the android studio.

I don't quite understand why these weird things are happening but assuming my recent upgradetion of my harddrive to SSD, which I copied the Ubuntu partion to the new SSD with third party partition manager tool has something for these overall cause.
So, hoping to get some light upon this weird problem.